# How do I find the fraction of this square that is the shaded upside-down kite shape?

Tags: geometry

[image]
In the diagram above, shape ABCD is a square and M is the midpoint on side AB.

What fraction of the square is shaded?

---

In attempting to solve this, I first drew lines at known midpoints:
[image]
The shaded area below is $\frac{1}{64}$, so two of them make $\frac{1}{32}$:
[image]
The shaded area below is $\frac{1}{32}$:
[image]
There are two, but I need to subtract two of this shape:
[image]
And that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: area of that small triangle will be $1/288+1/576$

Comment: How did you get that @Vasya?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make it a unit square with $C$ the origin and $D$ being $(1,0)$ you can write the equations for lines $CM$ and $AD$.  The intersection point is $(\frac 13,\frac 23)$ so the kite is composed of two isosceles triangles with base $(\frac 13,\frac 23)$ to $(\frac 23,\frac 23)$.  The one that has peak $M$ has altitude $\frac 13$.  The upside down one has altitude $\frac 16$.  The total area is then $\frac 12\cdot \frac 13(\frac 13+\frac 16)=\frac 1{12}$

Comment: What lines intersect at (1/3, 2/3)? Did you mean CM and BD?

Comment: No, CM and AD as I said.  The leftmost point of the kite.

Comment: Oops. My mistake. I reversed C & D in my diagram from the original problem.